# check if an array_values are null

Tags: php, arrays

Trying to submit a form if there are no error, the problem is the status of an array of errors, empty, null, or not set. none of these checks worked.

I'm sure there are better ways to get/collect errors messages and check an array, any suggestions are very welcome.

---

```
$validate = array();

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$validate[] = $user->inputLessThan($user->username, 8);
$validate[] = $user->emptyInput($user->firstName);
$validate[] = $user->emptyInput($user->lastName);
$validate[] = $user->emptyInput($user->email);
$validate[] = $user->validEmail($user->email);
$validate[] = $user->emailExists($user->email);
$validate[] = $user->emptyInput($user->phoneCell);
$validate[] = $user->validatePassword($user->password,$_POST['passwordConfirm']);



/* var_dump($validate); 
 * if all fields were filled properly returns all NULL. "no errors!"
 * array(8) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL [3]=> NULL [4]=> NULL [5]=> NULL [6]=> NULL [7]=> NULL }
 */


// try submitting the form if no errors stored in $validate && insert-to-db     
// if(!isset($validate)) {  
// if(is_null($validate)) {     
// if(empty($validate)) {
// if(array_values($validate) == NULL) {
// if(is_array($validate) && empty($validate)) {
// NONE of the above worked.

if(is_array($validate) && empty($validate)) {

            $hashedPassword = $user->hashPassword($user->password);
            $activationCode = $user->getActivationCode();

        if(is_array($userData)) {

            $userData['username']   = $user->username;
            $userData['firstName']  = $user->firstName;
            $userData['lastName']   = $user->lastName;
            $userData['email']      = $user->email;
            $userData['address']    = $user->address;
            $userData['country']    = $user->country;
            $userData['phoneCell']  = $user->phoneCell;
            $userData['password']   = $hashedPassword;
            $userData['active']     = $activationCode;

            }

            /* var_dump($userData); 
             * 
             * displays the array if checked with isset($validate) for debuging
             * 
             * 
             * ["username"]=> string(12) "userName@1.com" 
             * ["firstName"]=> string(12) "userName@1.com" 
             * etc.... }
             * registerUser method insters to db.
             */

            $user->registerUser($userData);

    }

/* loop to display errors, works.
*       if(isset($validate)){
*       foreach($validate as $error){
*           echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$error.'</p>';
*               }
*           }
* class methods are functioning. e.g.
*
*
*   public function emptyInput($input) {
*       if(empty($input)) {
*       return $error = "field cannot be empty.";
*           }
*       }       
*
* used as above $validate[] = $user->emptyInput($user->firstName);
* to add the method return message to the array $validate.
*
*/
```

Comment: Are all the comments in the code really necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try empty(array_filter($validate))

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

If your PHP version is <5.5 then split by two:

```
$validate = array_filter($validate);
if ( empty($validate) )
{

}
```